# How to get my dropdown divs positioned in the correct place?

Tags: jquery, html, bootstrap-4

When I click on my divs, I would like them all to be positioned in the same place, which is off to the right and below the div content, however they drop down in the same place as the divs I clicked on as if theyre all in a little box within eachother, if that makes sense. I'm not entirely sure how to get them all to move over to the right and stay there.

https://jsfiddle.net/frmLuvzn/2/

```
<div class="col-md-4">
 <div class="card mb-4 shadow-sm">
<div class="content">
  <div class="description">
    The First Album[1989]
  </div>
</div>
<div class="about-section">
  <p class="album">The First Album[1989]</p>
  <p>bands’ classic first record, produced by Mellisa Madrid with Floor, Jake Baker, Keifer Leblanch and Adrian Sherwood.</p>
  <div id="albumlist">
    <p>Tracklist </p>
    <ol class="albumlist">
      <li>Yes</li>
      <li>No</li>
      <li>Idk</li>
      <li>Can you repeat the question?</li>
     </ol>
   </div>
 </div>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
 <div class="card mb-4 shadow-sm">
   <!-- <img class="card-img-top" src="images/album1.jpg"> -->
</div>
 <div class="content">
   <div class="description">
  The Second Album[1990]
</div>
 </div>
  <div class="about-section">
    <p class="album">The Second Album[1990]</p>
  <p>bands’ classic first record, produced by Mellisa Madrid with Floor, Jake Baker, Keifer Leblanch and Adrian Sherwood.</p>
  <div id="albumlist">
    <p>Tracklist </p>
    <ol class="albumlist">
      <li>Yes</li>
      <li>No</li>
      <li>Idk</li>
      <li>Can you repeat the question?</li>
    </ol>
  </div>
  </div>

  </div>


 <div class="col-md-4">
 <div class="card mb-5 mb-4 shadow-sm">
  </div>
    <div class="content">
<div class="description">The Third Album[1990]</div>
 </div>
    <div class="about-section">

  <p class="album">The Third Album[1990]</p>
  <p>bands’ classic first record, produced by Mellisa Madrid with Floor, Jake Baker, Keifer Leblanch and Adrian Sherwood.</p>
  <div id="albumlist">
    <p>Tracklist </p>
    <ol class="albumlist">
      <li>Yes</li>
      <li>No</li>
      <li>Idk</li>
      <li>Can you repeat the question?</li>
    </ol>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
$(function() {
  $('.description').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('.content').siblings('.about-section').toggle(1000);
  })
})
```

Comment: Your question is a bit ambiguous. What do you mean by "I would like them all to be positioned in the same place"?

Comment: When I click on my div, I would like the clicked on and shown item to be floated to the right, instead they all seem to drop down below their respective divs.

Comment: @Mel why not use accordions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are better suited doing this using `flexbox`. Here is an example:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.description').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('.content').siblings('.about-section').toggle(1000);
  })
})
```

```css
.about-section{
  display:none;
 }

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.wrapper > div {
  flex: 0 0 33.33%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="card mb-4 shadow-sm">
    <!-- <img class="card-img-top" src="images/album2.jpeg"> -->
    <div class="content">
      <div class="description">
        The First Album[1989]
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="about-section">
      <!-- <p id="p1"><img class="float-left" src="images/album2.jpeg" style="width: 500px; height:500px"></p> -->
      <p class="album">The First Album[1989]</p>
      <p>bands’ classic first record, produced by Mellisa Madrid with Floor, Jake Baker, Keifer Leblanch and Adrian Sherwood.</p>
      <div id="albumlist">
        <p>Tracklist </p>
        <ol class="albumlist">
          <li>Yes</li>
          <li>No</li>
          <li>Idk</li>
          <li>Can you repeat the question?</li>
        </ol>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="card mb-4 shadow-sm">
    <!-- <img class="card-img-top" src="images/album1.jpg"> -->
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="description">
      The Second Album[1990]
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="about-section">
      <!-- <p id="p1"><img class="float-left" src="images/album2.jpeg" style="width: 500px; height:500px"></p> -->
      <p class="album">The Second Album[1990]</p>
      <p>bands’ classic first record, produced by Mellisa Madrid with Floor, Jake Baker, Keifer Leblanch and Adrian Sherwood.</p>
      <div id="albumlist">
        <p>Tracklist </p>
        <ol class="albumlist">
          <li>Yes</li>
          <li>No</li>
          <li>Idk</li>
          <li>Can you repeat the question?</li>
        </ol>
      </div>
    </div>

</div>


<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="card mb-5 mb-4 shadow-sm">
    <!-- <img class="card-img-top" src="images/town.jpg"> -->
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="description">The Third Album[1990]</div>
  </div>
      <div class="about-section">
      <!-- <p id="p1"><img class="float-left" src="images/album2.jpeg" style="width: 500px; height:500px"></p> -->
      <p class="album">The Third Album[1990]</p>
      <p>bands’ classic first record, produced by Mellisa Madrid with Floor, Jake Baker, Keifer Leblanch and Adrian Sherwood.</p>
      <div id="albumlist">
        <p>Tracklist </p>
        <ol class="albumlist">
          <li>Yes</li>
          <li>No</li>
          <li>Idk</li>
          <li>Can you repeat the question?</li>
        </ol>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```